# Menu Bar Not Visiblw in Andriod Studios

Tags: android, android-studio, android-menu

I made an app to learn how to add menu functionality in app. After following all the steps i am not able to get the three dot menu bar to access the menu.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTEBd.png)
was expecting a menu bar but there is nothing as such

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.