# Menu Bar not visible

Tags: android, android-menu

I made an app for menu in Android studios. I have done everything correct i belive still not getting the desired output. Made xml file and inflated it but its not visible when we run the app.[Menu xml file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUaFb.png)[java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIqz8.png) [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg1Dw.png)
No menu shown after inflating

Comment: are you create a menu file ?

Comment: *I have done everything correct* no, you don't ... how did you setup app theme ? ... Everything is official docs ....

Comment: Please check this link this will explain every step in detail explanation. https://www.javatpoint.com/android-option-menu-example

Comment: @HanifShaikh [Not about comment but deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: also you already asked [this question ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76781875/menu-bar-not-visiblw-in-andriod-studios)

Comment: I think you should have look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: @HanifShaikh no I m trying to understand how to create a menu interface in app